# I run the code in dolphindb, but get an error, how to solve it?

Tags: dolphindb

Run the code in dolphindb

I devide the time 2010.01.04 ~ 2021.01.01 into three parts: 2010.01.04 ~ 2015.01.01, 2014.01.04 ~ 2018.01.01, 2017.01.04 ~ 2021.01.01, then I can obtain the data correctly. But if I run such code as below:

```
res = s.run("select ts_code,trade_date,open,close from loadTable('dfs://xcsc_tushare', 'daily') where 
trade_date>=2010.01.04 and trade_date<=2021.01.01")
```

An error occur:

```
RuntimeError: <Server Exception> in run: Received invalid serialized data during deserialization!
```

Answer (score 0):

In the where clause, the data types should be the same in one judgment statement. Please check the type of the field “trade_date”. The time type of 2010.01.04 in dolphindb is date, so if the type of “trade_date” is not date, you can use the date() function to convert it. Conversion can be written as follows:

```py
date(trade_date)
```

So please confirm the type pf “trade_ date”.